# Opening a company page results in an error

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I found a job on the side bar that looks interesting. When I went an visited the job posting, I clicked on the company name under the job title:

[image: Link Clicked]

This resulted in an "Oops! Something Bad Happened" error.

---

This error also occurs if I click on the "We have 5 openings" link

[image: We have openings link]

---

Finally, I wanted to see if it happens with all companies and not just this specific one. It does. I tested by going to the [Companies](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies) page and trying to open any company. All of them return "Oops! Something Bad Happened"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a bit of an oopsie with respect to company pages today. It should be fixed within 10 minutes or so of this answer. Thanks for the report!

**EDIT**: It's now fixed.